# How to copy a stripe product from 'test' to 'live' with Python?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'd like to copy a bunch of stripe product objects created with my test keys over to my live keys, with as few changes as possible.
My rough plan would be to access the stripe api in python with my test key, run `product = stripe.Product.retrieve("prod_id")` then convert `product` into a dictionary by `prod_dict = json.loads(str(product))` then access the api with my live key and run `stripe.Product.create(prod_dict)` ... but this doesn't work.
My specific error is "stripe.error.AuthenticationError: Invalid API Key Provided: {'active*****..."
But I think that's a red herring. I'm pretty sure the issue is not the API Key, but rather that it's not actually acceptable to try to pass a dictionary as the argument for 'stripe.Product.create'. But I'm stumped as to how else to do what I want.
Has anyone else had the same issue and found a quick and easy solution?
My list of products is not large and I could, in theory, just do this by hand, but I'm worried about making some error in the copying process and, really, it doesn't seem like this should be very hard to do. Although, I'm often wrong about what should and shouldn't be easy to do. In any case, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given that your list of products is not large I would recommend doing this manually through the dashboard. If you click on a given product in test-mode under: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/products, you should see a button with three dots at the top of the product view (next to the "+Add pricing plan") docs. This will open a dropdown with the option to "Copy product to live mode": https://pasteboard.co/J65ZIp3.png

Comment: Oh, fantastic. Thank you, @ttmarek. Not exactly the solution I thought I was looking for, but better: simpler and easier.

Comment: That button does not exist in the latest dashboard. Is there any way to do this now through the dashboard?

Comment: @NateLevin if you click on a product in Test mode you should see a "Copy to live mode" button at the top right of the product page next to a '...' button.

Comment: Note, you have to go into the individual product's page to get the "copy to live mode" button. Not the product overview page.